# Can anyone help a stupid developer trying to set up Office 365 Exchange?

Tags: exchange, outlook, microsoft-office-365, android

As a Microsoft MVP, I have access to Office 365, with a limited number of users.  I'm trying to figure out how to set it up, but I'm running in to issues everywhere (I get the basics - just trying to make it all work end-to-end well).

Here's my scenario:  I have my primary email adam@notMyRealDomain.com, as well as a business email (I run my own company) - adam@notMyRealCompany.com.  In addition, I run a developer conference, and would like to send email out through a number of aliases / shared folders: speakers@myConference.com, sponsors@myConference.com and maybe info@myConference.com.  I have a co-leader of the conference who will need access to those mailboxes as well.

All domains are set up. Shared Mailbox is the more appropriate word. As the primary user, I want my personal, business and conference email to be viewable in one place, but separate folders, and I need to be able to send email so it looks like it comes from those alternate email addresses

I need this to work well everywhere - outlook.office365.com, MS Outlook on my laptop/desktop, and on my Android phone.

I've tried setting adam@notMyRealCompany.com as a shared mailbox, which works, but none of the android clients can see the folder.  So as a correlating question, which android apps support shared folders from Office 365?

I'm also getting an error when I try and send email from the shared mailbox in Outlook.

> Your message did not reach some or all of the intended recipients.
>   Subject: testing Sent: 11/18/2014 10:18 AM The following recipient(s)
>   cannot be reached: '[removed to protect the innocent]@gmail.com' on
>   11/18/2014 10:18 AM This message could not be sent. Try sending the
>   message again later, or contact your network administrator. Error is
>   [0x80070005-00000000-00000000]

Thanks in advance.  IT / Server guys don't get enough respect from developers - I personally think you guys are awesome. ;)

Comment: And be careful with that.  There's a reason that Microsoft are pushing O365 so hard.  Once you migrate to the cloud and get rid of your on-prem stuff, it becomes a major undertaking to migrate back to on-premises, and away from the recurring monthly fees you'll be charged for the Office cloud.  It's not crystal clear what context this is in, but if it's a pilot or trial for the broader company, that's an often overlooked consideration that I've already seen bite a few organizations pretty hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here for steps on creating the shared mailbox and adding the appropriate permissions, etc. http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/226425.aspx

A shared mailbox won't be accessible from an Android mobile device short of using OWA on that device. For your error check here: http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/158/t/158919.aspx

Basically drop and recreate the Outlook profile and the error should go away.